# Looping Methods needed here

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a query with the help of one experienced person from progress 4GL but i missed one concept to ask. I have shared the query. Here what i need is to calculate the total orders based on start and end hour for every shift sequence (Total 21 seq) and assign to variable. For example look below

```
 DEFINE VARIABLE StartHour06 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
 DEFINE VARIABLE StartHour07 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO

FIND FIRST gdmf_shift WHERE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence = 1 NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
StartHour06 = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
StopHour07 =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
```

Like this i need to write the query up to 21 shift sequence..actually its not a good code..i need to make it simple and tried one method but from that i don't know how to do assign to variables. Please look below what i tried

```
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* end hour */ 
FOR EACH gdmf_shift WHERE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence LE 21 NO-LOCK BY gdmf_shift.shft_sequence:
sSeq[1] = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
eSeq[21] =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
DISP sSeq[1] eSeq[21].
```

END.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep track of up to 21 individual shift sequences. Perhaps you should do something like the code below.

Right now you just update sSeq[1] and eSeq[21] for each iteration of the loop.

Insert shift sequence as index of the array instad:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq AS INTEGER EXTENT 21 NO-UNDO. /* end hour */ 
FOR EACH gdmf_shift WHERE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence LE 21 NO-LOCK BY gdmf_shift.shft_sequence:
  sSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence] = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
  eSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence] =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
  DISP sSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence] eSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence].
END.
```

If you absolutely need individual variables instead on extents its would be a lot more code and a CASE-statement (could be an IF as well) deciding what variable to assign:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq1 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq1 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* end hour */ 
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq2 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq2 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* end hour */ 
/* More variables here... */
DEFINE VARIABLE sSeq21 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* start hour */
DEFINE VARIABLE eSeq21 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO. /* end hour */ 


 FOR EACH gdmf_shift WHERE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence LE 21 NO-LOCK BY gdmf_shift.shft_sequence:
   CASE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence:
     WHEN 1 THEN DO:
      sSeq1 = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
      eSeq1 =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
    END.
     WHEN 2 THEN DO:
      sSeq2 = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
      eSeq2 =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
    END.
    /* more code here */
    WHEN 21 THEN DO:
       sSeq21 = gdmf_shift.shft_start_hour.
       eSeq21 =  gdmf_shift.shft_stop_hour.
    END.
  END CASE.
END.
```

But that will be LOTS of code. Consider using something like a temp-table instead if you dont like the array. If you name the fields in the temp-table like the names in the table you can use `BUFFER-COPY` otherwise you can `ASSIGN` any field.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO
  FIELD shft_sequence   LIKE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence
  FIELD shft_start_hour LIKE gdmf_shift.s.shft_start_hour
  FIELD shft_stop_hour LIKE gdmf_shift.s.shft_stop_hour.


FOR EACH gdmf_shift WHERE gdmf_shift.shft_sequence LE 21 NO-LOCK BY gdmf_shift.shft_sequence:

  CREATE tt.
  BUFFER-COPY gdmf_shift TO tt.

END.
```

Comment: yes i can do that but inside that iteration is that possible way to assign every start and end hour to individual variables per shift??upto 21 sequences??

Comment: In my code I set sSeq based on the shift sequence `sSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence] `

Comment: Yes sir..but the problem is how can i assign start and end hour to variables for every shift seq??

Comment: you have assigned every start and end hour data for 21 shift sequence in just two variables i.e sSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence] , eSeq[gdmf_shift.shft_sequence]..actually what i need is for every shift have to assign two variables.

Comment: sSeq[1] and sSeq[2] will still keep individual values so if they are the same variable or not is more of a theoretical question. If you really want totally separate varaibles (I dont understand why) you will need to write lots of code. I added an example, as well as one using temp-tables instead.

Comment: Actually sir we are the company producing car seats and using progress 4gl language..for your understanding 1 seat is called 1 work order..so in progress database name called gdmf_shift_maintenance which has shift hours on production..so we need to calculate how many work orders(seats) produced per shift hour..upto 21 shift..thats y i need to assign values to every variables

Comment: Using variables for this is senseless, what happens when a new shift is added?  You create a new variable and write some more code?  A temp-table is much more flexible and the code will be more robust.

Comment: I agree with Tom, you just need to use one field that defined as extent and add the extent number when needed is more flexible rather than use many variables.